# Configure network to allow QEMU to reach internet

Tags: networking, qemu, bridge, tap

I have the following standard configuration:

- A remote server connected to internet and that I can only control using SSH
- On this server, a QEMU instance

I'm trying to find the right configuration so the QEMU instance has access to the internet (so I can can download files from QEMU).

From what I've read I must use TAP network, but I'm not totally sure of what it is.

Following tutorials, I've successfully created a "tap0" interface. Also, according to the documentation I've been following [1], I must set-up a "bridge". Then I add the interface "tap0" to the bridge, and I'm supposed to add the physical interface "eth0" as well. Unfortunately, as soon as I add the physical interface to the bridge, I lose the SSH connection to the server (and I really need to avoid this).

Is there a way to have a configuration allowing this:

- Allow the QEMU instance to access to internet
- Keep the SSH access to the server
- Eventually forward some specific ports from the host to the QEMU instance

EDIT: My current /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto tap0
iface tap0 inet static
        pre-up tunctl -t tap0
        address 192.168.101.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.10
        network 192.168.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        bridge_ports enp1s0 tap0
        up brctl stp br0 on
```

The output of ifconfig:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 186.165.216.145  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 188.165.215.255
        inet6 2001:41d0:2:a28c::  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe7b:a1a0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:25:90:7b:a1:a0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7463  bytes 785704 (767.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 471  bytes 48743 (47.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:58:62:89:a3  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 186.165.216.145  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 188.165.215.255
        ether 00:25:90:7b:a1:a0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 43202  bytes 6202060 (5.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 7  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 41815  bytes 13945866 (13.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xfbce0000-fbd00000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 10792  bytes 11008366 (10.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10792  bytes 11008366 (10.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tap0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.101.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.101.255
        ether b2:ab:00:ed:63:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10  bytes 882 (882.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 801  bytes 50917 (49.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

[1] http://www.shakthimaan.com/installs/debian-tun-tap-setup.html

Comment: Regarding the second point: You probably lose connection because the bridge has no IP address. It's best to define the bridge in /etc/network/interfaces (if the server's distro is Debian) as documented in https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration. Point 3 (port forwarding) requires iptables manipulation, specifically the FORWARD chain.

Comment: @berndbausch Indeed, manually setting a IP to the bridge seems to fix the SSH connection issue, yet I still can't connect to the internet from QEMU. I've added my host configuration to my post for information.